# What's the equivalent of CAGradientLayer in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, core-animation

I'm trying to port over some objective-C code that creates a gradient layer

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.colors = colors;
gradientLayer.locations = locations;
gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds;

[view.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:index];
```

However in Swift, CAGradientLayer does not seem to have a static 'layer' method or a constructor. Trying to use it as a type produces:

```
let a:CAGradientLayer? = null
```

> Error: Use of module 'CAGradientLayer' as a type

As far as I can tell, CAGradientLayer is not a module I can import. What's the correct way of doing a gradient layer in Swift?

Comment: Can't assign to null unless it's an optional, firstly.  Did you try assignment to an inited gradient layer?

Comment: BTW use nil, not null.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to import QuartzCore first:

```
import QuartzCore

let a:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
```

Comment: You can omit the type, as well (i.e., `let a = CAGradientLayer()`).